# Executing addon code upon browser startup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like for my addon to reload an internal page (index.html) upon browser startup, if its tab exists. This is the code I am using, but nothing happens at all. Am I doing the right thing? The docs seem to say that this is the proper way to do it.

```
exports.main = function(options) {
  var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
  if (options.loadReason === 'startup') {
    for (var i = tabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var tab = tabs[i];
      if (tab.url !== self.data.url('index.html')) {
        continue;
      }
      tab.once('ready', runScript.bind(null, tab));
      tab.reload();
    }
  }
};
```

It is hard to debug because when doing `cfx run` the loadReason is always `install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Tested this and it appears that at the time `main()` is called the session restore changes are not yet propagated (in a way the SDK understands).

Using a `setTimeout(..., 0)` fixed that behavior:

```
const self = require("sdk/self");
const selfTabUrl = self.data.url("index.html");
console.log("self", selfTabUrl);

function runScript(tab) {
  console.log("runScript", tab.url);
}

function reloadTab(options) {
  var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
  for (var i = tabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var tab = tabs[i];
    if (tab.url !== selfTabUrl) {
      continue;
    }
    tab.once('ready', runScript.bind(null, tab));
    tab.reload();
    console.log("reload", tab.url);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

exports.main = function(options) {
  if (options.loadReason === 'startup') {
    if (!reloadTab()) {
      console.log("didn't find a tab on first attempt; retrying");
      require("sdk/timers").setTimeout(reloadTab, 0);
    }
  }
};
```

This works in Firefox Stable (29) and avoids the `setTimeout` should the behavior be changed later.

Regarding the debugging:
To avoid having `cfx run` setting up and re-installing (instead of re-using a profile and just starting the extension) use the `--profiledir=` switch, e.g. (on a *nix system)

```
$ mkdir p # run once
$ cfx run --profiledir=$PWD/p
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for an elaborate answer! Now the question is why is that `setTimeout` necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `const { loadReason } = require("sdk/self");` and check `if (loadReason == "startup")`